# libgdx android studio json skin label error

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to create skin label in libgdx(scene2d) using Android Studio. Pretty sure I didn't make any mistake in json file since I'm copying code from working tutorial. 
Method where I want to initiate skin:

```
private void initLabel() {
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin.json"));
    label = new Label("Score: ", skin);
}
```

Json file (was trying to use "// @formatter:off" and many other options always getting similar error):

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle:{
default: { font: default-font, fontColor: white } }
```

Error that I'm getting:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: uiskin.json
                                                                at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:98)
                                                                at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:75)...

... Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing JSON on line 3 near: ne2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle:{
                                                                *ERROR*default: { font: default-font, fontColor: white }
                                                             }
```

Even if I commit typo mistake or anything like that I'm still getting this cause part of an error : "line 3 near: ne2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle:{                                                          *ERROR*default: { font:"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post your complete `.json` file ?, Is it your [default](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/uiskin.json) libgdx .json file ?

Comment: I think you suggest some part was missing and you were right. Here's full working json label skin file: `{
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: pixelfont.fnt } },
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
 green: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 1, r: 0 },
 white: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
 red: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 1 },
 black: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 0 },
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
 default: { font: default-font, fontColor: white }
},
}`

Answer (score 0):

This is due to there is no default-font defined in the app you created. The tutorial code leaves you to create a font name default-font and add it to the skin later. So what you need to do is generate a new font then add it to the skin and finally initiate the skin.json file.

```
    private BitmapFont font;

    private void initLabel() {
    //create a bitmap font of your choice
    font = new BitmapFont();
    //create the skin using default constructor
    skin = new Skin();
    skin.add("default-font",font); 
    skin = Skin.load(Gdx.files.internal("skin.json"));
    label = new Label("Score: ", skin);
    }
```

The important part is `skin.add("default-font",font);` the name you enter need to be the same also in the skin.json file which is `font: default-font` in your case.